# Can't increase heap size IntelliJ Mac – changed idea.vmoptions+restarted

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, heap-size

I'm on MacOs 10.13.4 (High Sierra)
Using IntelliJ 2020.3.1 (Community Edition)

I've tried increasing the heap size but failed. I've tried these two things:

1. Changing through the dialog box Help->Change Memory Settings. But I get stuck with the spinning cursor and have to force quit IntelliJ. However when I restart IntelliJ the memory is increased. But when I run something that requires a lot of heap size I get "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".
2. Changing directly in the idea.vmoptions file. Changing "-Xmx750m" to e.g. "-Xmx8096m". But after restart of IntelliJ I still get: "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".
   [IntelliJ->Help->Edit Custom VM Options...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOk58.png)

I have run the exact same files in Eclipse after increasing the heap size there to 4096 mb. Therefore I know the problem isn't that the program I run need more heap space than that. To me it seems like there's no effect from the increase.

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: could you please share idea.log (Help | Show log...) after restarting IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

> File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Compiler->Shared build process heap size (Mbytes)

[image]